# align text side by side to figure

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

How can I put the figure on left and text on right and align it left (the text)?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "George"
date: "12/3/2018"
output:
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---

    ```{r global, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(GGally)


x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(11,22,33)
z <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Introduction
=======================================================================

### General info

- A

- B



Corr
=======================================================================

### Correlation

Here is some text

- One
- Two

```{r}
renderPlot({
    GGally::ggpairs(z)
})

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, this layout fills the page completely and gives prominence to a single chart on the left where you can have your img and two secondary charts included to the right- where you can have your text

````
 title: "Focal Chart (Left)"
    output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
    ---

    Column {data-width=600}
    -------------------------------------

    ### Chart 1

    ```{r}
    ```

    Column {data-width=400}
    -------------------------------------

    ### Chart 2

    ```{r}
    ```   

    ### Chart 3

    ```{r}
    ```
````

Comment: Hi, even though your approach works for my example, it doesn't work for my updated question example.Is there any solution for this?I want to have a tabset and in each of them have a figure and text.

Comment: I figured that what I want is not possible yet (https://github.com/flexdashboard/issues/37).Is there a way to align the text? Or color it? I tried to use `renderText({"hello", "<fint color=\"#FF0000\"><b>"})` but it doesn't work

Comment: you could create a seperate css file and import it  --- output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css  and in your css file put .text{
  color:red;
  align: left;}

Comment: im quite new with using flexdashboard aswel, but hope that helps abit.